# How to get object which stream?

Tags: node.js, stream

I have something like this:

```
//open new socket for every webSocket connection
**socket**.pipe(controller);//controller is writable stream of course

//in controller we have:
controller.prototype._write =function(chunked, encoding, callback){ 
    //here -> how to get **socket** object which piped ?    
    //in 'this' we have controller object
}
```

It is even possible ? If not try suggest solution how to get this object. I need this because I send response.

EDIT:
I wanna write simple CHAT. Don't have code yet( I have basic engine skeleton).
I can write about it, but the better option is paint:

[image: engine schema]
In picture I don't clearly mention that I have var SOCKETS - which store all connection sockets, so Controller know all socket.
The problem is that Controller, precisely some function listener for event(response for createRoom,privMessage) don't know from which socket data come from.

Comment: in this case you should not use pipe, because pipe suppose that if the source end emitting events the destination is closed too, you have to maintain an array of sockets (each with an identifier) and in messages you will have to define the destination socket and it's expeditor (like in usual post mail :D )

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the source on `pipe` event:

```
controller.on('pipe', function (/* **socket** */) {
    // Save a reference to the socket
});
```

So you can create a wrapper to get a reference:

```
function wrap(controller) {

    var socket = null;

    controller.on('pipe', function (source) {
        socket = source;
    };

    controller.prototype._write =function(chunk, encoding, callback) {
        if (socket) {
            // Do something with socket
        } else {
            // Do something else
        }
    }
}
```

and use the code:

```
var myController = new Controller();

wrap(myController);

mySocket.pipe(myController);
```

Comment: Yes, we can. But event ‘pipe ’ is fired only once when I call socket.pipe(controller).
I need now which socket send data and to THAT socket send response.
Any suggests how to do it ?

Comment: @SonnyD, updated answer, if you could show more of your code I could understand more of what you need.

Comment: Okay I wrote something more about what I wanna do.